# Incrementally updating an Nhibernate entities values concurrently

Tags: nhibernate, concurrency, fluent-nhibernate

I'm fairly new to NHibernate - please bear with me.

So, I have an Nhibernate entity, which is mapped fluently. It has an integer property which I want to increment, and that's it - nothing else is updated etc.

How can I ensure concurrency when two or more clients are updating the same entity? Does NHibernate take care of this for me out of the box?

Cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NHibernate will help, how it depends on which concurrency model you want to use. There is a [beautiful post by Ayende](http://ayende.com/blog/3946/nhibernate-mapping-concurrency) that you should read.

Comment: This is a good link, thanks. Pessimistic Concurrency looks the way to go. I'll lock the row and both updates can succeed after waiting if necessary.